# MS way to (Python) code Edge session using Selenium 4

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, microsoft-edge

*OS - Windows 10
Selenium - 4
Python - 3.9.7
Browser - MS Edge (v97)
Edge Driver (v97)*

Whilst the following code works, albeit with an error thrown, it seems (according to MS) that the Selenium 4 approach is to use 'official EdgeOptions and EdgeDriver classes from the OpenQA.Selenium.Edge namespace':

```
import unittest
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.edge import service
from selenium.webdriver.edge.options import Options

class Login(unittest.TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        
        s=service.Service(r'C:\Users\Path_to_driver\msedgedriver.exe')
        self.driver = webdriver.Edge(service=s)
        url = "https://my_website"
        self.driver.get(url)
```

Thing is, as a newbie to Python OO and Selenium, i'm badly floundering on how to do this and all of my web searches have failed to provide an answer that I can understand. I can't even find OpenQA.Selenium.Edge, EdgeOptions or EdgeDriver, which is not a good start! :-/

Ideally i'd like to use the Selenium 4 method and so i'd be really grateful if anyone can provide me with some pointers. TIA

Comment: The "OpenQA.Selenium.Edge namespace" is a C#/.NET concept.  It doesn't apply to Python.  If it works as is, then you have nothing to worry about.

Comment: Ah OK, thanks Tim

Comment: May I know if you have got any chance to check my answer? I am glad to help if you have any other questions.

Answer (score 2):

I agree with @TimRoberts mentioned, but if you want to implement your requirement in Python, you can also use [msedge-selenium-tools] for Selenium 3 (https://pypi.org/project/msedge-selenium-tools/).

Simple code:

```
from msedge.selenium_tools import Edge, EdgeOptions

# load the desired webpage
edge_options = EdgeOptions()
edge_options.use_chromium = True
edge_options.binary_location = r"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft\Edge\Application\msedge.exe"

driver = Edge(options = edge_options, executable_path=r"C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\msedgedriver.exe")
driver.get('<your website url>')
```

**Edit**:

Or you can use the built-in EdgeOptions in Selenium 4. Simple code below:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.edge import service

edgeOption = webdriver.EdgeOptions()
edgeOption.use_chromium = True
edgeOption.add_argument("start-maximized")
edgeOption.binary_location = r"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft\Edge\Application\msedge.exe"
s=service.Service(r'C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\msedgedriver.exe')
driver = webdriver.Edge(service=s, options=edgeOption)
driver.get("<your website url>")
```

**Note:**
msedge-selenium-tools should be uninstall to use Selenium 4.

Comment: Many of the solutions suggest that approach, but I don't believe it is appropriate to Selenium 4!? This from MS:

If you use Selenium 4, you don't need to use Selenium Tools for Microsoft Edge. Selenium Tools for Microsoft Edge are for Selenium 3 only. It's this that sent me around in circles trying different things, but failing miserably.

I was hoping to determine a W3C way of doing it, as that seems to be the approach.

Comment: Well, if this is the case, you could use the built-in EdgeOptions in Selenium webdriver. Simple refer to my edited answer.